# ReactJS: send object as parameter to function, the fields are undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm react beginner. strange behavior: 
I send an objct as parameter to a function. the function get the object , but the function can access field of this object. the fields are undefined.

I send the object 'movie' to the  handleClickDelete. see the console logs: the 'movie' object is correct. but the movie._id is undefined.

the component:

---

```js
class MainList extends Component {
  state = {
    count: APIMovieService.getMovies().length,
    movies: APIMovieService.getMovies()
  };

  handleClickDelete = movie => {
    console.log("delete movie", movie);
    console.log("delete movie Id", movie._id);

    const updateList = this.state.movies.filter(
      iMove => iMove._id === movie._id
    );
    // APIMovieService.deleteMovie(movie._id);
    console.log("updateList: ", updateList);
    this.updateState(updateList);
  };

  updateState = updateList => {
    this.setState({ movies: updateList });
    this.setState({ count: updateList.length });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.handleCounter()}
        {this.test1()}
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">title</th>
              <th scope="col">genre</th>
              <th scope="col">in stock</th>
              <th scope="col">rate</th>
              <th scope="col">delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
              <tr key={movie._id}>
                <td scope="row">{movie.title}</td>
                <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
                <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
                <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.handleClickDelete({ movie });
                    }}
                  >
                    delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleCounter() {
    return this.state.count === 0
      ? "the list is empty"
      : this.state.count + " in the list";
  }

 

export default MainList;
```

the log:
see picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1eeq.png)

Comment: Just use `this.handleClickDelete(movie);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
onClick={() => {
this.handleClickDelete({ movie });
}}
```

To :

````
onClick={() => {
this.handleClickDelete(movie)
}};```
````

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the movie inside an object movie.

For access the properties you need to access another movie property before, like this.

movie.movie.__id

To avois this behavior you need to change this:

```js
onClick={() => {
  this.handleClickDelete({ movie });
}}
```

For this

```
onClick={() => {
  this.handleClickDelete(movie);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `movie` as an object. You need to pass it as a variable like:

```
<button
   className="btn btn-danger"
   onClick={() => this.handleClickDelete(movie)}
>
   delete
</button>
```

Now you can access it in your `handleClickDelete`

```
const handleClickDelete = movie => {
    console.log("delete movie", movie);
    console.log("delete movie Id", movie._id);
}
```

Hope this works for you.